# How to bind scroll event on element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, bind

How can I bind scroll event on element in AngularJS directive ?

I bind scroll on $window, but now i need to change it to this class ".body-wrapper" (angular.element(document.queryselector(.body-wrapper)) doesn't work) .

Any ideas ?

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () { 
   ...
})
```

Comment: Here's a nice example that supports mouse wheel scrolling even if the element doesn't have scrollbars and also can tell which direction you are scrolling in http://demo.sodhanalibrary.com/angular/directive/mouse-wheel-event.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No reason it shouldn't work.

This simple example shows it does-

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('.myDiv')).bind('scroll', function(){
      alert('scrolling is cool!');
    })
});
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FUEyaZb03hl6KmKPKEVV?p=preview)

if for some reason it is not working, post full code.

Edit after discussion:

Eventually the problem is with the specific event for "scroll", it probably collides with another event.

Changing the event to "mousewheel" did the trick.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13pnp6qa/)

Comment: Thanks , but how can i use it in directive ? 
angular.element(document.querySelector('.ngscroll-container')).bind('scroll', function(){
      alert('scrolling is cool!');
});  Doesnt work

Comment: Is the ".ngscroll-container' is in the html template of the directive?

Comment: Its generated from another angular directive (Custom scrollbar)

Comment: Can you post your code or part of it that is working and showing the bug?

Comment: Can you add the html to the fiddle?

Comment: Hi :) 
I have updated your [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxnvafoz/1/) , see whats the problem here , <.ngscroll-container> generated from scrollbars directive. Please check jsfiddle .

Comment: You are not calling the directive 'loadMore' anywhere... how to you expect it to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144933/discussion-between-ziv-weissman-and-aro-tonoyan).

Answer (score 11):

You would normally make a new directive for that.

```
app.directive('scroll', [function() {
  return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('scroll', function (e) {
        // do your thing
      });
    })
  }
}]);
```

Now, use this directive where ever you need to add the scroll event.

```
<div class='.body-wrapper' scroll></div>
```

Directives are the preferrd and cleaner approach to accessing DOM elements in Angularjs, instead of `angular.element`.

Comment: This way is good too , but i have some problem ... in main directive im already used another elem . I can use 2 directive but its not the best way i think :/

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Having two directives on one element, or having directives inside another directive's template is not an issue. You probably are already using other directives (like ngClick, ngHref) in that manner.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way I have found is:

```
(function() {
  angular
  .module('yourAppName')
  .directive('scrollDirective', ['$window', scrollDirective])

  function scrollDirective($window) {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var handler;
        $window = angular.element($window);

        handler = function() {
          console.log('scrolling....')
        };

        $window.on('scroll', handler);
      }
    };

  };

})();
```

then you can use it in your Html as:

```
 <div scroll-directive="">a long list goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**mousewheel** event triggers the scroll event to the window than a **scroll** event.

```
angular.element($window).bind('mousewheel', function () {  
  // enter code here  
}
```

Comment: You can scroll an element without using the mouse wheel, so this answer may not work in all cases.