# Getting alert on end on div

Tags: angularjs

I want to call alert box when i reached end of div

Help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100583/876739 and

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('.test')).bind('scroll', function(){
     console.log('in scroll'+this.scrollTop +' '+this.offsetHeight+' '+this.scrollHeight);
      if (this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight > this.scrollHeight) { //at the bottom
   alert("at bottom");
  }
   });

});
```

```css
.test{
  overflow-y: scroll; height:100px; 
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<div class="test">
 Photography is the science, art, application and practice of creating durable images by recording light or other electromagnetic radiation, either electronically by means of an image sensor, or chemically by means of a light-sensitive material such as photographic film.[1]

Typically, a lens is used to focus the light reflected or emitted from objects into a real image on the light-sensitive surface inside a camera during a timed exposure. With an electronic image sensor, this produces an electrical charge at each pixel, which is electronically processed and stored in a digital image file for subsequent display or processing. The result with photographic emulsion is an invisible latent image, which is later chemically "developed" into a visible image, either negative or positive depending on the purpose of the photographic material and the method of processing. A negative image on film is traditionally used to photographically create a positive image on a paper base, known as a print, either by using an enlarger or by contact printing.

Photography is employed in many fields of science, manufacturing (e.g., photolithography), and business, as well as its more direct uses for art, film and video production, recreational purposes, hobby, and mass communication
</div>
</body>
```

How to achive this?

Comment: what is not working at this time? You need to be more specific. Give some output of your logging or something else this is just asking if we can make your problem go away without knowing whats wrong

Comment: alert is not showing

Comment: please debug the application to see if your queryselector is working for example. If it works try someting different e.a.: click function instead of scroll

Comment: Yes query selector is working on scrolling shoing `in scroll`

Comment: `if (this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight > this.scrollHeight) { ` is not working i think so

Comment: try to write the values of scrollTop offsetHeight and scrollHeight to console to see whats happening

Comment: this.scrollHeight is always greater then both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171966/discussion-between-xrcwrn-and-jordy-van-eijk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is fixed. if you look at your `if` you do `>` but if you never get higher than the value you need to do `>=` larger of equal

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('.test')).bind('scroll', function(){
     console.log('in scroll'+this.scrollTop +' '+this.offsetHeight+' '+this.scrollHeight);
      if (this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight >= this.scrollHeight) { //at the bottom
   alert("at bottom");
  }
   });

});
```

```css
.test{
  overflow-y: scroll; height:100px; 
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<div class="test">
 Photography is the science, art, application and practice of creating durable images by recording light or other electromagnetic radiation, either electronically by means of an image sensor, or chemically by means of a light-sensitive material such as photographic film.[1]

Typically, a lens is used to focus the light reflected or emitted from objects into a real image on the light-sensitive surface inside a camera during a timed exposure. With an electronic image sensor, this produces an electrical charge at each pixel, which is electronically processed and stored in a digital image file for subsequent display or processing. The result with photographic emulsion is an invisible latent image, which is later chemically "developed" into a visible image, either negative or positive depending on the purpose of the photographic material and the method of processing. A negative image on film is traditionally used to photographically create a positive image on a paper base, known as a print, either by using an enlarger or by contact printing.

Photography is employed in many fields of science, manufacturing (e.g., photolithography), and business, as well as its more direct uses for art, film and video production, recreational purposes, hobby, and mass communication
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an equal not superior :D

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('.test')).bind('scroll', function(){
     console.log('in scroll');
      if (this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight == this.scrollHeight) { //at the bottom
   alert("at bottom");
  }
   });

});
```

```css
.test{
  overflow-y: scroll; height:100px; 
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<div class="test">
 Photography is the science, art, application and practice of creating durable images by recording light or other electromagnetic radiation, either electronically by means of an image sensor, or chemically by means of a light-sensitive material such as photographic film.[1]

Typically, a lens is used to focus the light reflected or emitted from objects into a real image on the light-sensitive surface inside a camera during a timed exposure. With an electronic image sensor, this produces an electrical charge at each pixel, which is electronically processed and stored in a digital image file for subsequent display or processing. The result with photographic emulsion is an invisible latent image, which is later chemically "developed" into a visible image, either negative or positive depending on the purpose of the photographic material and the method of processing. A negative image on film is traditionally used to photographically create a positive image on a paper base, known as a print, either by using an enlarger or by contact printing.

Photography is employed in many fields of science, manufacturing (e.g., photolithography), and business, as well as its more direct uses for art, film and video production, recreational purposes, hobby, and mass communication
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply check for greater than equals to
`this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight >= this.scrollHeight` 
it will work.